# Symbolic Link not working in sub-directory?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, symbolic-link, ln

Newbie here. I was learning about `ln` command. So I created a symlink to a file foo.txt inside another directory bar.

```
ln -s foo.txt bar
```

When I try to access `bar/foo.txt`, I get the error "**Too many levels of symbolic links**". Can anyone explain symbolic links a little more? And what I tried to do is not possible or is there another way of achieving it? Basically i want a link to foo in directory bar which is in the same directory as foo.

```
directory
|__foo.txt
|__bar
   |__(link to foo.txt)?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symlink targets are stored as raw paths (hence 'symbolic' link). By default, when you use `ln -s` the target path is stored *literally* – it's not made relative, it's stored just as you specified it.

Relative paths must therefore be specified as if they were relative to the link's location, *not* relative to your current location:

```
ln -s ../foo.txt bar/foo.txt
```

Because the link is in `bar/`, the link will lead to `bar/../foo.txt`.

Creating relative links will be much easier if you first `cd` to where the link will be (as then the link's location and your current location will be the same).

On recent Linux, the `ln` command has an additional `-r` option to simplify this and create relative links the way you expect them to work:

```
ln -r -s foo.txt bar/foo.txt
```

(Notice that after you do this, the link's target will automatically become `../foo.txt` again.)

On Linux you can try using the `namei` command to get a visual representation of how a certain path (including symlinks) is followed.

Comment: Thanks for replying. A couple of questions: "ln -s ../foo.txt bar/foo.txt" where should I run this command? Doesn't seem to work in the directory or in bar. Also does it mean symlinks cannot be moved?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? What results does it give? Does it create a wrong link, does it show an error message, does it have no visible effect at all? Symlinks can be moved but their target will not auto-adjust – if it was stored as `../foo.txt` it will remain stored as `../foo.txt`, so if e.g. you move the symlink one level up (or down) it'll indeed break after moving... but if you move both the link and the original in the same way, it'll keep working.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I made a mistake. It works as intended. Thanks a lot.